# MacOS:python: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Requirement: I have a script that has a python command to run and the script is used by everyone

Error: python: command not found

Example:

```
cat test.sh                                                                                                                         
python -c "import json,sys;"
```

If I change the script from `python -c`  to `python3 -c` it works fine

Also, my ~/.zshrc as below

```
# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr//bin/pip3
```

I already have python on my macOS as below

[image]

**Issue is when running python inside the shellscript**

How to get the shell script to run the python command in it?

Also why is it blank when running below command
[image]

Comment: How to get the script run with python

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the homebrew installer itself, be sure to add this to your .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

:( Above worked only one time but next time i ran it threw same error python command not found

Comment: Updating a variable that's already in the environment _always_ exports the new value. `PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` would have the exact same effect with no `export` present.

Comment: You are right it didnot work again after sometime :(

Comment: What does `declare -p PATH` emit when it _doesn't_ work?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  `export -T PATH path=( /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin /Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS /Users/karthik/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin )`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Issue is only when running a shell script with a python command in it ...

Comment: That `declare -p` output looks like it's from your copy of zsh, not from the shell script that didn't work. What does it look like when it's run _inside the script_? (May require a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang instead of a `#!/bin/sh` shebang)

Comment: ...assuming they're different, the question then is how exactly the script is started -- what its parent process was, what the relationship is between that parent process and the shell in question.

Comment: Same script works fine in my colleagues MacOS

Comment: That statement doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: We use flyway which executes the script and in the script calls the python

Comment: Okay, in that case you want to pay attention to flyway's environment variables. Environment variables are inherited from the parent process; they're not globally configured, so you need to pay attention to which variables are set for whichever process _starts_ the script you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Finally below solved my problem

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`